# Finding the cause of a layout request in a ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Launcher-like side-scrolling custom ViewGroup that contains a RelativeLayout in each "page". Within this RelativeLayout I have some other views that log when onMeasure() is called.
When I flip to another page, onMeasure is called six times for each view. I have already eliminated some TextViews because they request layout passes when the text changes, but I cannot find the other causes for layout requests.

Does anybody know a trick to find cause for layout requests within a ViewGroup?

On a related note, does anybody know a trick to make sure that TextViews do not cry for layout requests when the text changes? There are some hints buried in the sources ([http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/widget/TextView.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/widget/TextView.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) around line 5500), but I couldn't make it happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextView needs a layout pass when the text changes, you can't really work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Romain. Do you know any way of checking for the cause of the layout request? I have removed all TextView updates and still get two requests.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in requestLayout() at the highest level you can and look at the stack (you could also dump the stack from code.)

Answer (score 0):

I was updating 2 TextViews at 1 fps (each), and still the main thread was using more CPU then my GLSurfaceView...

Actually setting a fixed width either with `android:layout_width` or `android:ems` stops the layout requests. You may also want to use `setText(char[] text, int start, int len)` instead of `setText(CharSequence)` to avoid having a String created.